# MPOW headphones: turn off bluetooth, turn on usb

Tags: sound, usb, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm running Kubunto 20.04. I have a pair of MPOW headphones. I can get them to connect to my laptop fairly consistently over Bluetooth.  They  don't show up on **lsusb** at all, even when they are plugged into a USB port. Distance isn't an issue.

I sometimes want to feed them through the USB connection to save battery juice. So I connect them to the laptop using a USB to phono cable.  That sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, and I can't figure out what makes the difference.  There are several variables in play: whether the cable is plugged into the headset, whether the cable is plugged into the laptop, whether Bluetooth is active on the headphones, and  how the **pulseaudio** volume control is set up. Sometimes the headphones show up in **pulseaudio** and sometimes they don't. There also seem to be some sequence dependencies in the behavior.

I'm pretty sure I have all the necessary hardware and software components properly installed, since it does work occasionally. I just haven't been able to untangle the logic. There must be a consistent sequence of actions that will get me to a working USB connection from a working Bluetooth connection, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is. Can anyone advise me?

*Edit 1:* I went to bed with the computer connected only by Bluetooth.  I woke up to discover that the USB connection I had wanted did indeed show up, and **pulseaudio** now showed three lines instead of two. So simply waiting long enough affects the situation, but "long enough" is, or can be, more than a few minutes. The new connection still didn't show up in **lsusb**.

Comment: Distance wouldn't be an issue if they're plugged into USB unless you have a really, *really* long cable  / Probably unrelated, but I have a similar issue with a set of Logitech Bluetooth headphones. They will only play over USB when the battery is fully charged (on both Ubuntu and macOS).